# Spring GraphQL server closes websocket connection: 4400 Invalid Message (works on Graphiql)

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, graphql, spring-webflux, apollo-client

I am working on GraphQL communication between a Spring server and a Next.js client. Recently I've changed the server's GraphQL dependency (I am converting to WebFlux) and that's when my subscriptions stopped working - the server closes the websocket connection with a `4400` code immediately.

[image]

The same subscription with the same payload works just fine on `/graphiql`.
[image]

This started happening when I switched to this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and this code:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @Autowired
    private PagePublisher pagePublisher;

    @SubscriptionMapping("scrapesPerformed")
    public Publisher<String> getScrapesPerformed() {
        return pagePublisher.getScrapesPublisher();
    }
}
```

In the previous, working implementation I was using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and exposing the publisher like this:

```
@Component
public class PageSubscription implements GraphQLSubscriptionResolver {

    @Autowired
    private PagePublisher pagePublisher;

    public Publisher<String> getScrapesPerformed() {
        return pagePublisher.getScrapesPublisher();
    }
}
```

If anyone's interested - I am using `Apollo Client` on front-end, like this (nothing's changed here):

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: SPRING_SERVER_ENDPOINT,
});

const wsLink = process.browser ? new WebSocketLink({
    uri: SPRING_SERVER_SUBSCRIPTIONS_ENDPOINT,
    options: {
        reconnect: true
    },
}) : null;

const link = process.browser ? split(
    ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation }: Definintion = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
) : httpLink;

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({ link, cache });

export default client;
```

with `useSubscription`:

```
const SUBSCRIBE_TO_SCRAPES_PERFORMED = gql`
    subscription Subscription {
        scrapesPerformed
    }
`;

export default function SpringServerHeartbeat() {
    const { data, loading } = useSubscription(
        SUBSCRIBE_TO_SCRAPES_PERFORMED
    );

    const subscription_data = (
        loading ?
            <div className='spinner-border mx-auto'/>
            :
            data ?
                <h4>
                    {data.scrapesPerformed}
                    <br/>
                </h4>
                :
                null
    );

    return subscription_data;
};
```

Can anyone with some of Websocket knowledge (I have none :D) please help me out with at least some pointers of what that means? I was google'ing this Bad Request message, but found nothing; and I'm pretty sure the payload is correct...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to switch from an older `graphql-transport-ws` protocol (used on my server in the previous implementation) to a `graphql-ws` on the client side.